# Stack Overflow is not accepting my questions

Tags: support, asking-questions, new-users, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

I don't know why some of my questions are voted negatively. 15 days back, I asked those questions but today they are negatively voted. Why hasthis happened?

Further, Stack Overflow is not accepting my questions today. How can I refresh my account so that I can ask questions? I am new new to Android development and also new to this site.

Comment: You've asked 18 questions in 15 days. That's a lot of questions. What was the message you received?

Comment: @ChrisF Hi,  when ever I click ASQQUESTION its showing WE ARE NO LONGER ACCEPTING THE QUESTIONS.......

Comment: You have questions with correct answers you've not accepted. The formatting of the code in your questions leaves a lot to be desired. You asked identical questions as well it appears. Work on improving your questions and you'll likely receive good answers and fewer downvotes.

Answer (score 7):

It's not SO that voted your questions negatively, it's the community (ie: other users.)

It's a sign that people looked at such questions and thought they cannot help you because there is something wrong with said question.

For the error you got, check [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

Comment: thanks for the Information ,but how can I refresh my account

Comment: what do you mean by "refresh my account", there is no way you could refresh your account.

Comment: @ meta.DavRob60 I mean how can I reactivate my account?

Comment: Did you follow the link I added to my answer?